# Modal no muestra valores que estan encerrados en comillas

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, modal

Tengo un datatable que muestra una serie de valores cada linea de la tabla tiene un botón, el cual carga un modal, para poder mostrar los valores contenidos en cada linea con su respectivo botón se utiliza el siguiente código, le quite muchos datos solo estoy exhibiendo el que tiene este detalle:

```html
<button type="button" id="recargarSolicitud_TrasladoActivo" class="btn btn-success paste"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSolicitud_TrasladoActivo"   data-descripcion="<?=$DescripcionSolicitudTraslado?>" data-keyboard="false" data_backdrop="static" title="SOLICITUD DE TRASLADO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>
</button>
```

Se tiene una función js la cual edite solo para señalar donde tiene el problema:

```js
$('#modalSolicitud_TrasladoActivo').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

                  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Botón que activó el modal
                  
                  var Descripcion = button.data('descripcion');// Extraer la información de atributos de datos
                  var modal = $(this);
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('TRASLADO DEL ACTIVO:');//
                modal.find('.modal-body #DescripcionSolicitud_TrasladoActivo').val(Descripcion);
                  
               $('.alert').hide();//Oculto alert
            });

            // funcion para restablecer los modales (resetear)
            $("#btnCerrarSolicitud_TrasladoActivo").click(function(event) {
                  $("#formSolicitud_TrasladoActivo")[0].reset();
            });

      });
```

De esta manera al hacer clic en el botón, carga el modal, previa la carga de datos por el js y se muestran en el modal.  el detalle que tengo es que aquellos valores cargados desde la base de datos que contengan cadenas como "Valor" ,  "valor , " y similares y parecidos no los muestra en el campo indicado en el modal.

¿ Que se podría hacer para que si los muestre?

Gracias

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que un valor de atributo que tenga comillas dobles *rompe* la estructura HTML, por ejemplo:

Separando en líneas para verlo más fácilmente aquí:

```
<button type="button"
    id="recargarSolicitud_TrasladoActivo"
    class="btn btn-success paste"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modalSolicitud_TrasladoActivo"
    data-descripcion="Esta "descripción" tiene comillas"
    data-keyboard="false"
    data_backdrop="static"
    title="SOLICITUD DE TRASLADO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>
</button>
```

En este caso, el navegador interpretará `data-descripcion="Esta "` como un atributo correcto y `descripción" tiene comillas"`, en el mejor de los casos, será omitido.

Ahora, suponiendo que el valor solo contiene unas comillas dobles:

```
data-descripcion="Esta descripción" tiene comillas"
```

El navegador tomará `data-descripcion="Esta descripción"` y las comillas al final de  `tiene comillas"` harán que el resto de atributos no se puedan interpretar, incluso puede que ni siquiera aparezca el botón o que todo el HTML posterior se muestre de forma incorrecta.

Solo necesitas codificar la cadena para convertir caracteres HTML en sus correspondientes entidades con [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<button type="button"
    id="recargarSolicitud_TrasladoActivo"
    class="btn btn-success paste"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modalSolicitud_TrasladoActivo"
    data-descripcion="<?= htmlspecialchars($DescripcionSolicitudTraslado); ?>"
    data-keyboard="false"
    data_backdrop="static"
    title="SOLICITUD DE TRASLADO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></span>
</button>
```

El resultado será algo como:

```
data-descripcion="Esta &quot;descripción&quot; tiene comillas"
```

Comment: Muy bien paisano, como siempre una excelente aportación, sobre todo la explicación del por que sucede y luego el como se puede resolver.  Ahí te debo una craft beer .  Saludos

Comment: @Cesarin, tú dirás... ya se acerca mi _"BeerDay"_ ;-)

Comment: pa cuando ? :)?

Comment: El 21 sumo otros 365... ¿más?... efectivamente. ;-)

Comment: orales!!!  pues asi es la vida....cada segundo cuenta jejeje